# Parsing identical elements from separate blocks. Error: Repeating an entry in an array output

Tags: python, arrays, parsing

I wrote a crooked parser code.
I'm trying to write a parser to get several identical elements from the site, located in separate blocks.
Here is the parser code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

URL_TEMPLATE = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/rr.html"
FILE_NAME = "img.csv"


def parse(url=URL_TEMPLATE):
    result_list = {'id': []}
    result_l = {'id': []}
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
    vacancies_names = soup.find_all('ul', class_='PhotoListSmall')
    vacancies_li = soup.find_all('li')
    for name in vacancies_names:
        for i in vacancies_li:
            result_list['id'].append(i.a['href'])
        result_l['id'].append(result_list['id'])
        result_list['id'] = []

    return result_l


df = pd.DataFrame(data=parse())
df.to_csv(FILE_NAME)
```

Here is the page the parser is processing

```
<ul class="PhotoListSmall">
        <li class="one">
            <a href="one_1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="two">
            <a href="one_2"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="PhotoListSmall">
        <li class="one">
            <a href="two_1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="two">
            <a href="two_2"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And this is what I get

```
,id
0,"['one_1', 'one_2', 'two_1', 'two_2']"
1,"['one_1', 'one_2', 'two_1', 'two_2']"
```

And here is what I want to get

```
,id
0,"['one_1', 'one_2']"
1,"['two_1', 'two_2']"
```

What have I done wrong?

Do not judge strictly, I'm just a beginner developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the `soup` which is having all the `li` elements from both of the `PhotoListSmall` class in it. That's why it's appending the same array twice.

To get the `li` from only one class at a time, create another soup inside the loop, instead of using the original soup.

```py
for name in vacancies_names:
    li_soup = bs(str(name), "html.parser")
```

the new soup should have the `name` as its data, so that it can only have access to the li elements of the first `PhotoListSmall` class. now create the `vacancies_li` and find all `li` elements from the `li_soup`.

The final code should look something like this.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

URL_TEMPLATE = "http://192.168.100.196:5500/test.html"
FILE_NAME = "img.csv"


def parse(url=URL_TEMPLATE):
    result_list = {'id': []}
    result_l = {'id': []}

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")

    vacancies_names = soup.find_all('ul', class_='PhotoListSmall')
    # vacancies_li = soup.find_all('li')

    for name in vacancies_names:
        li_soup = bs(str(name), "html.parser")
        vacancies_li = li_soup.find_all('li')

        for i in vacancies_li:
            result_list['id'].append(i.a['href'])

        result_l['id'].append(result_list['id'])
        result_list['id'] = []

    return result_l


df = pd.DataFrame(data=parse())
df.to_csv(FILE_NAME)
```

I hope it helped you :)